# jQuery animate function work only one time

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-animate

I have a switch in SVG using the jQuery animate function, but apply on the "cs" attribut of my "circle" SVG element.

```
$('#filtres-reglages ul li label input:checkbox').click(function (e) {
    var oswitch = $(this).parent().find("svg#switch");
    var path = oswitch.find("path");
    var circle = oswitch.find("circle");

    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(circle).animate(
            {'foo':20},
            {
                step: function(foo) {
                    $(this).attr('cx', 10+foo);
                },
                duration: 200
            }
        );
    } else {
        $(circle).animate(
            {'foo':20},
            {
                step: function(foo) {
                    $(this).attr('cx', 30-foo);
                },
                duration: 200
            }
        );

    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<label>
    <svg id="switch" class="switch-off" xml:space="preserve" enable-background="new 0 0 40 20" viewBox="0 0 40 20" y="0px" x="0px" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
        <g>
            <g>
                <path d="M30,0L30,0L30,0H10C4.5,0,0,4.5,0,10c0,5.5,4.5,10,10,10h20l0,0h0c5.5,0,10-4.5,10-10C40,4.5,35.5,0,30,0z " fill="#CCCCCC">
            </g>
            <g>
                <circle r="8" cy="10" cx="10" fill="#FFFFFF">
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
    <input type="checkbox" name="champs_societes[]" value="capital_int">
    <span>Capital</span>
</label>
```

When my checkbox is checked I increment cx, when is not checked, I decrement.

But the progressive animation is working only the first time. After that, the switch goes directly from 30 to 10, and from 10 to 30. Why ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Please add a minimal working example to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is animate foo from 0 to 20 and then back to 0 again.

What you were actually doing was 0 to 20 and then to 20.  But on the second part you were subtracting the value from 30, so you were actually just jumping from 20 to (30-20) in one animation step.

Here's what you should have been doing:

```js
$('label input:checkbox').click(function (e) {
    var oswitch = $(this).parent().find("svg#switch");
    var path = oswitch.find("path");
    var circle = oswitch.find("circle");

    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(circle).animate(
            {'foo':20},
            {
                step: function(foo) {
                    $(this).attr('cx', 10+foo);
                },
                duration: 200
            }
        );
    } else {
        $(circle).animate(
            {'foo':0},
            {
                step: function(foo) {
                    $(this).attr('cx', 10+foo);
                },
                duration: 200
            }
        );

    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
    <svg id="switch" class="switch-off" xml:space="preserve" enable-background="new 0 0 40 20" viewBox="0 0 40 20" y="0px" x="0px" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
        <g>
            <g>
                <path d="M30,0L30,0L30,0H10C4.5,0,0,4.5,0,10c0,5.5,4.5,10,10,10h20l0,0h0c5.5,0,10-4.5,10-10C40,4.5,35.5,0,30,0z " fill="#CCCCCC"/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <circle r="8" cy="10" cx="10" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
    <input type="checkbox" name="champs_societes[]" value="capital_int">
    <span>Capital</span>
</label>
```